# sync data between to tabs/sheets columns with the same columns in each

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hello Trying to write a simple formula to have two people enter the same data in each of their tabs in the same google sheet--workbook ( no script)
I created the identical row on both tabs. Colum R 1-196 only using R9—196 for data It would be the same data. With all cells using plain text numbers from
2022-000000 and 0000   So if person 1 enters the data or person 2
Both tabs/sheet colums will get populated with the data.  I just don't know how to write it and where to write it.

=DailyAlarmsReport_Online    sheet/tab 1

=May_LiveTracking    shhet/tab 2

=’DailyAlarmsReport_Online’!R9:R196. To =’May_LiveTracking’!R9:R196
And =’May_LiveTracking’!R9:R196 to =’DailyAlarmsReport_Online’!R9:R196

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/160Ua.jpg) [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZqiYe.jpg)

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 0):

you will need a 3rd tab that would compile data from those 2 sheets. formula would be for example:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF('DailyAlarmsReport_Online'!R9:R196=""; 'May_LiveTracking'!R9:R196; 'DailyAlarmsReport_Online'!R9:R196))
```

Comment: ok thank you, still trying to get this sruff